# JQuery Slider Show is sliding two images at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a slider which uses JQuery to either automatically slide images, or slide when the user presses a button. When I implement on my site, the slider will always initiate twice, skipping one image. This happens when you press a button as well as if you set it to work automatically. However, when I copied the code to a JSFiddle, the function worked fine and only progressed by a single image. What could cause this?

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pgr6W/)

And the HTML, JS:

HTML

```
    <div id="slider">
        <button class="control_next">&#171;</button>
        <button class="control_prev">&#187;</button>

        <ul>
            <li>SLIDE 1</li>
            <li>SLIDE 2</li>
            <li>SLIDE 3</li>
            <li>SLIDE 4</li>
        </ul>  
    </div>

    <div class="slider_option">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
        <label for="checkbox">Autoplay Slider</label>
    </div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

/*JQuery for fade in highlighting of links*/
$(".link").hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({ color:'#fe57a1'}, 100);
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({ color: '#fff'}, 300);
});


jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    $('#checkbox').change(function(){
        setInterval(function () {
            moveRight();
        }, 3000);
    });

    var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
    var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
    var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
    var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

    $('#slider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });

    $('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });

    $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

    function moveLeft() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: + slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    function moveRight() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: - slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };



    $('button.control_prev').click(function () {
        moveLeft();
    });



    $('button.control_next').click(function () {
        moveRight();
    });

});
});
```

Comment: Given that it works perfectly in the JSFiddle example, you probably have other elements or styles conflicting with the slider.

Comment: As it works in JSFiddle - try commenting out code until it works on your website to try to find the error.

Comment: in the fiddle to I experienced your problem!!!!....

Comment: $('#checkbox').change(function(){
        setInterval(function () {
            moveRight();
        }, 3000);                                                              
    });  have you used this code in your site too.

Comment: Thanks everyone. The problem was there were two `<script>` tags, one in the `<head>` and another in the `<body>`.

Comment: The slider works great for me. However, I would do the link hover animation in css.